# File manager that shows bit rate for mp3 files

Tags: audio, software-rec, file-manager

I am a Fedora user and my current file manager is Thunar. The OS is quite nice but I am not satisfied with Thunar. There are a lot of features I think it's lacking but mainly I am missing more urgently two:

1. having a straightforward way to search files in my machine, and,
2. when viewing files as a detailed list, having a column showing the bit rate of my mp3's files so I don't have to go Right Click -> Properties -> Audio -> Properties on each file to know if it is 128kbps, 256kbps or 320kbps.

I would like to receive some advise on a file manager meeting this two needs.

Comment: Almost any decent file manager does this.

Comment: Not true unfortunately. I have tried almost half a dozen (Dolphin, Xfe, PCManFM, Thunar and Krusader) and they lack one of the two, most commonly the second.

Comment: You are right. I checked out nautilus and saw that it has the feature, and presumed that other file managers should do it.

Comment: Not sure why this should be closed -- he's asking about the presence of a specific feature rather than the relative merits of one program or another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Nautilus](https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Apps/Nautilus?action=show&redirect=Nautilus) has these features.

```
sudo yum -y install nautilus
```

Launch `nautilus` and there will be a magnifying glass in the top right corner, this can be used to search for files.

Navigate to your MP3 folder and select `Edit->Preferences` and select the "List Columns" tab.
Select "Bitrate" and close.

[image]

> **[EDIT]**
>
> It appears this is an Ubuntu specific plugin called Nautilus Columns
>   that uses Python. More info on that here,
>   http://www.webupd8.org/2012/05/add-pdf-audio-and-exif-metadata-to.html
>
> I am currently downloading Fedora and will try to build this plugin
>   and update with instructions.

Comment: [Apparently this requires a plug-in or a specific version of Nautilus or something.](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/150876/file-manager-that-shows-bit-rate-for-mp3-files-part-2)

Comment: @Gilles, it appears you are correct. This is an Ubuntu specific plugin using Python. I think I found the source and will try to write some instructions but I don't have a RHEL based system. I'm running Arch.